# How to get full amino acid name from translating a sequence in R?

Tags: r, sequence, fasta

I want to translate the first 15 bases of a sequence and then find the name of the last amino acid from this. I have my fasta file.
The fasta file is for the MTHFR sequence for the human genome.

```
library("Biostrings")
myseq <- readDNAStringSet("sequence (1).fasta", format = "fasta")
head(myseq)
```

The output of this looks like:

```
DNAStringSet object of length 1:
width seq                                   names
```

`[1] 20374 ATGACGATAAAGGCACG...AAACAAAAAAACTTGAC NC_000001.11:c118...`

to try and get the first 15 amino acids to translate i did:

```
for(n in 1:15){translate(myseq, genetic.code = GENETIC_CODE)}
```

but I don't think this code is correct in trying to find the answer.

Comment: can you give us a [mcve]?  You appear to be using Bioconductor packages: can you tell us which ones?

Comment: I am using biostrings package.

Comment: OK.  How about a [mcve], i.e. show us what `myseq` is?

Comment: oh ok  myseq <- readDNAStringSet("sequence (1).fasta", format = "fasta")
myseq is a fasta file about the MTHFR sequence in human genome

Comment: Can you give us a short part of the sequence that don't require to download the file. Like `head(myseq)` ?

Comment: When i did head(myseq), I got: DNAStringSet object of length 1:
    width seq                                   names               
[1] 20374 ATGACGATAAAGGCACG...AAACAAAAAAACTTGAC NC_000001.11:c118...

Comment: please include all those things you've told us in the comments as part of your question ... thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

```
library("Biostrings")
myseq<-DNAString("ATGACGTGTTCGTGT") #Read string as DNAstring object
myaa<-translate(myseq) #Translate to aa
my3laa<-AMINO_ACID_CODE[unlist(strsplit(as.character(myaa),NULL))] #Get 3-letter code
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your example:

```
library(Biostrings)
myseq <- DNAStringSet("ATGACGATAAAGGCACG")
```

This gives you the first 15 base pairs:

```
subseq(myseq[[1]],1,15)
  15-letter "DNAString" instance
seq: ATGACGATAAAGGCA
```

And translate this:

```
translate(subseq(myseq[[1]],1,15))
  5-letter "AAString" instance
seq: MTIKA
```